# Evaluating $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}}{(1-2\sin(x))}^{\tan(\frac{\pi}{6}-x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm in a little struggle with this limit, can anyone help me, please?

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}}{(1-2\sin(x))}^{\tan(\frac{\pi}{6}-x)}$$

I tried to use the logarithm to then use L'Hospital's rule but I got stuck here: 
$\ln(L)=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}}{[\tan(\frac{\pi}{6}-x)\ln(1-2\sin(x))]}$

Thank you!

Comment: First bring it into the form $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ and then apply the mentioned theorem.

Comment: FYI L'Hopital Rule is applied when there is *fraction*. See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule).

Comment: I did it but it leads to that logarithm/( 1/0 ) and 1/0 doesn't exist

Comment: write it as $$\frac{\ln(1-2 \sin x)}{\cot \left(\frac{\pi}{6}-x\right) }$$ and use the fact that $\cot \left(\frac{\pi}{6}-x\right) \to \infty$ and $\ln(\ldots) \to ????$as $x \to \frac{\pi}{6}$.

Comment: but ln(1/0) isn't an indeterminate form it's undefined

Comment: @MathAnimal I tried but when verifying, the numerator is 1/0 $\ln(L)=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}}{\frac{\ln(1-2\sin(x))}{\frac{1}{\tan(\frac{\pi}{6}-x)}}}$

Comment: @So Ming Chun but 1/0 sure is.

Comment: @CookieDog, use the standard table limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$

Comment: @Cheesecake that $\sin(x)$ is negative, I don't think I can apply the remarcable limit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the limit $ \lim_{x\to a^+} \frac{\cos(x)\ln(x-a)}{\ln(e^x-e^a)} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538846/finding-the-limit-lim-x-to-a-frac-cosx-lnx-a-lnex-ea)

Comment: @Cheesecake listen, I haven't worked with limits for a while, I don't really remember much but I am pretty sure that that that remarcable limit works only on positive x. I might be wrong, I might be right, I'm enoughly confused by other things right now than by this limit. If you can't help me, fine, I don't oblige you.

Comment: It makes no difference.

Comment: I apologise, I missed something, my bad.

Comment: There is a related question [$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}x^x=0, \  \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln x}{x}=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1378682/721644).

Comment: Are you sure the limit is meant to be $2$-sided? If $x$ is slightly larger than $\pi/6$, $1-2\sin x<0$, so $(1-2\sin x)^{\tan(\pi/6-x)}$ isn't real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x) = (1-2\sin x)^{\tan(\frac{\pi}{6}-x)}$, then $f(x) = e^{g(x)}$ with $g(x) = \tan(\frac{\pi}{6}-x) \log (1-2\sin x)$.

$$\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}^- } g(x)
&= \lim\limits_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}^- } \frac{\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-x\right)}{\frac{\pi}{6}-x} \left(\frac{\pi}{6}-x\right)\log \left(1-2\sin x\right)
\\
&\overset{(1)}{=} \lim\limits_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}^- } \left(\frac{\pi}{6}-x\right)\log \left(1-2\sin x\right)
\\
&=\lim\limits_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}^- } \frac{ \log (1-2\sin x)}{\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{6}-x}}
\\
&\overset{\mathrm{H}}{=} \lim\limits_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}^-} (-2\cos x)\frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-x\right)^2}{1-2\sin x}
\\
&= -\sqrt{3}\lim\limits_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}^-} \frac{\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-x\right)^2}{1-2\sin x}
\\
&\overset{\mathrm{H}}{=}
-\sqrt{3}\lim\limits_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}^-}\frac{-2\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-x\right)}{-2\cos x }
\\
&= 0
\end{align}$$
where in $(1)$ I have used $\lim_{y\to0} \frac{\tan y}{y} = 1$ and $H$ denotes the usage of *L'Hôpital's rule*.

Hence, we conclude that

$$\lim\limits_{x \to \frac{\pi}{6}^-} f(x) = e^0 = 1.$$

Comment: Thanks but why did you wrote $x \to \frac{\pi}{6}^{-}$? My limit is a two-sided one.

Comment: @user3669039 I've edited the formatting of your algebra for readability. It is generally easier for people to follow equations separated by lines instead of written sequentially on the same line.

Comment: @Jam Thank you very much

Comment: @CookieDog  The limit cannot be two-sided: we must guarantee $1-2\sin(x)>0$ in order for your function to be defined.

Answer (score 2):

In the "$\log$" expression, expand $\sin$ around $x_0=\frac{\pi}{6}$ using Taylor series, up to the second term, get 
$$
\sin x \approx \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)
$$
so the expression $\log(1-2 \sin x)$ becomes $\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \left(\frac{\pi}{6} - x\right)\right) = \log \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \log \left(\frac{\pi}{6} - x\right)$. Now set $t=\frac{\pi}{6} - x$, rewrite $-\tan (-t_ = -\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}$ and expand $\sin t \sim t $ for $t \to 0^+$. This additional condition of convergence from the right allows rewriting the limit as

$$
\lim_{t \to 0^{+}} t \log t
$$

Now you can rewrite $t \log t = \frac{\log t }{\frac{1}{t}}$, and note that $\frac{1}{t} \to \infty$ and $\log t \to -\infty$. Set $\log t =v, \frac{1}{t} = e^{-v}$ for $v \to \infty$ and obviously 
$$
\lim_{v \to \infty}\frac{v }{e^v} = 0
$$
All other terms converge to constants and are easy to compute. Keep in mind also that the original expression is $\varphi = e^{\log \varphi}$, so don't forget to take the exponent.

Result: no L'Hopital Rule used, only Taylor Series Expansion!

Comment: There is a problem with your Taylor expansion, it should be $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(\frac{\pi}{6}-x)$

Comment: thanks @user3669039, fixed

Answer (score 2):

Your job might be simpler if you substitute $\pi/6-x=2t$. Then
$$
1-2\sin x=1-2\sin(\pi/6-2t)=1-\cos 2t+\sqrt{3}\sin 2t=2\sin t(\sin t+\sqrt{3}\cos t)
$$
Note that in order that the limit makes sense you need $\sin x<1/2$, so $0<x<\pi/6$ (the lower bound is mostly irrelevant, though), hence $t>0$.

How does this help? You get to evaluate the limit for $t\to0$ of
$$
\tan2t\bigl(\log(\sin t)+\log(2\sin t+2\sqrt{3}\cos t)\bigr)
$$
The part $\tan2t\log(2\sin t+2\sqrt{3}\cos t)$ poses no problem: its limit is $0$. Then you need to compute the limit of
$$
\frac{2\cos t}{\cos2t}\sin t\log\sin t
$$
The fraction part has limit $2$. The part $\sin t\log\sin t$ has limit $0$, as it's easy to show with l'Hôpital or other methods.

Hence the limit is $0$. Therefore your original limit is $e^0=1$.