# Differentiate $f(x) = xe^x$ from first principles

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to prove the derivative of $f(x) = xe^x$ is $f'(x) = e^x + xe^x$ from first principles.

The derivative is $ \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} $ as h tends to zero

So:

$ \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}  =  \frac{(x+h)e^{x+h} - xe^x}{h} $

$ = \frac{x(e^{x+h}-e^x)+he^{x+h}}{h} $

$ = \frac{x(e^{x+h}-e^x)}{h} + e^{x+h} $

This tends to infinity as h tends to zero. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: How did you determine that the last expression tends to infinity as $h\to 0$?

Comment: Then you are having the same problem with differentiating $e^x$...

Comment: $ \frac{x(e^{x+h}-e^x)}{h} + e^{x+h}=x e^x \frac{e^{h}-1}{h}+ e^{x+h}$ could help.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thanks but then how would I prove $ \frac{e^h-1}{h} $ does not tend to infinity?

Comment: Do you know the expression in power series, or Taylor series, for $\;e\;$ ?

Comment: Just because that, close to $h=0$, $e^h\approx 1+h$. I am sure that you have that somewhere in your notes. Is it OK ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @Timbuc now that's an interesting exercise (no sarcasm intended). How to determine the power series expansion of $e$ with only basic math tools (no fancy tools such as calculating derivatives et al.)

Comment: @user3371583 I don't think that's possible, yet this question's tagged "Differential Equations", so "fancy tools" as derivatives, integrals and the multiplication table of number 8 most likely are old news.

Comment: @Timbuc It's most likely a mistag. Someone who knows differential equations wouldn't be taking derivatives from the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{x(e^{x+h}-e^x)}{h}=\frac{x(e^x\cdot e^h-e^h)}{h}
=
\frac{xe^x(e^h-1)}{h}=xe^x\frac{e^h-1}{h}
$$
and the limit of the last factor is the derivative of $t\mapsto e^t$ at $0$, so it is $1$ rather than infinity.

How do you compute it? It depends on how you define $e$: if you define $e$ as the only number $a$ such that
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a^h-1}{h}=1
$$
then you're done.

If you define $e=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n$ then much more work needs to be done. First show that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\!x}=e=
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\!x}
$$
Then we can do the substitution $x=1/t$ and get
$$
\lim_{t\to0}(1+t)^{1/t}=e
$$
so, by continuity of the logarithm,
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\log(1+t)}{t}=1
$$
Now set $\log(1+t)=h$ so that $t=e^h-1$; therefore
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h}{e^h-1}=1
$$

Answer (score 2):

You have incorrectly evaluated the limit of $\frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}$, which tends to $e^x$, rather than to infinity as $h$ tends to zero.

Note that $\frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}$ is the standard difference quotient in the computation of the derivative of $e^x$.

Comment: but surely this equals $ \frac{(e^{x+h})}{h} + \frac{e^x}{h} $ which is infinite regardless because $ \frac{e^x}{h} $ is infinite

Comment: how did the minus sign turn into a plus sign?

Comment: sorry, my bad, how do I prove that $ \frac{e^x+h}{h} $ isnt infinite though?

Comment: $\frac{e^{x+h}}{h}$ does tend to infinity, but so too does $\frac{e^x}{h}$.  To evaluate their difference is equivalent to taking the derivative of $e^x$.  How reasonable this is as a task depends on how you defined $e$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know/can use power/Taylor series, then

$$\frac{e^h-1}h=\frac{1+h+\mathcal O(h^2)+\ldots-1}{h}=1+\mathcal O(h)\xrightarrow[h\to 0]{}1$$

Answer (score 0):

Use

$\dfrac{d[f(x)\cdot g(x)]}{dx}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h)g(x+h)-f(x)g(x)}h$

$=\lim_{h\to0}f(x+h)\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{g(x+h)-g(x)}h+g(x)\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$

Set $f(x)=x,g(x)=e^x$ or $g(x)=x,f(x)=e^x$

Finally use $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{e^h-1}h=1$

Comment: Im struggling with that last line, how does one prove $ e^h / h $?

Comment: @KVohra95, See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42679/proof-of-fx-ex-1-x-1-text-as-x-to-0-using-epsilon-delta-definiti and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152605/proving-that-lim-limits-x-to-0-fracex-1x-1. There are many other sources available in internet

Comment: @KVohra95 First prove that $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\ln(y+1)}{y}=1$ ($\lim_{y\to 0}\ln\left( (1+y)^{\frac{1}{y}} \right)=\ln\lim_{y\to 0}\left( (1+y)^{\frac{1}{y}} \right)=\ln e = 1$). Now let $u=e^y -1$. Then $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{e^y-1}{y}=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{u}{\ln(u+1)}=1$.