# Notable limit of exponential

Tags: calculus, limits

Why does $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{e^x -1}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{e^x -1}=1 $ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proof of $ f(x) = (e^x-1)/x = 1 \text{ as } x\to 0$ using epsilon-delta definition of a limit](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42679/proof-of-fx-ex-1-x-1-text-as-x-to-0-using-epsilon-delta-definiti)

Comment: or of [Proving that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/152605). Please search before asking.

Comment: L-hopitals rule can also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use L'Hopital's Rule:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{x}-1}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}e^{x}-1}{\frac{d}{dx}x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}e^{x} \rightarrow 1$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{e^{x}-1} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}x}{\frac{d}{dx}e^{x}-1} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{e^{x}} \rightarrow 1$$