# Evaluate $\lim_{k\to l}\frac{\sqrt{e^{\sin(2k)}}-\sqrt{e^{\cos(2k)}}}{k-l}$ without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate $$\lim_{k\to l}\frac{\sqrt{e^{\sin(2k)}}-\sqrt{e^{\sin(2l)}}}{k-l}$$

I know this is equivalent with $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{e^{\sin(2x)}}=\cos(2x)\sqrt{e^{\sin(2x)}}$, but my instructor wants me to solve this using limit. My attempt:

Multiply with $\frac{\sqrt{e^{\sin(2k)}}+\sqrt{e^{\sin(2l)}}}{\sqrt{e^{\sin(2k)}}+\sqrt{e^{\sin(2l)}}}$

$$ \frac{1}{2}\lim_{k\to l}\frac{e^{\sin(2k)}-e^{\sin(2l)}}{(k-l)(\sqrt{e^{\sin(2l)}})}$$

Here's where I stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\to l}\frac{\sqrt{e^{\sin(2k)}}-\sqrt{e^{\sin(2l)}}}{k-l}
&=\lim_{k\to l}\frac{e^{\sin(2k)}-e^{\sin(2l)}}{(\sqrt{e^{\sin(2k)}}+\sqrt{e^{\sin(2l)}})(k-l)}\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt{e^{\sin(2l)}}}\lim_{k\to l}\frac{e^{\sin(2k)}-e^{\sin(2l)}}{k-l}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{e^{\sin(2l)}}}{2}\lim_{k\to l}\frac{e^{\sin(2k)-\sin(2l)}-1}{k-l}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{e^{\sin(2l)}}}{2}\lim_{k\to l}\frac{e^{2\cos(k+l)\sin(k-l)}-1}{2\cos(k+l)\sin(k-l)}\cdot\frac{\sin(k-l)}{k-l}\cdot 2\cos(k+l)\\
&=\cos(2l)\sqrt{e^{\sin(2l)}}\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}\right)\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x\right)\\
&=\cos(2l)\sqrt{e^{\sin(2l)}}.
\end{align*}
The without-L'Hospital proof for last two limits can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684535/geometrical-proof-of-the-limit-lim-x-to-0-left-fracex-1x-right-1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Your last line must be
$$\frac{e^{\sin(2k)}-e^{\sin(2l)}}{(k-l)(\sqrt{e^{\sin(2k}}+\sqrt{e^{\sin(2l)}})}$$

Comment: No, it is a correction of the mistake by the OP!

Comment: Yes, but this is still not an answer to the question.

Comment: The question seems to be "Here's where I stuck" ... So are you sure that this is not an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{k\to l}\frac{\sqrt{e^{\sin(2k)}}-\sqrt{e^{\sin(2l)}}}{k-l} =\lim_{k\to l}\frac1{\sqrt{e^{\sin(2k)}}+\sqrt{e^{\sin(2l)}}}\cdot\lim_{k\to l}\frac{e^{\sin(2k)}-e^{\sin(2l)}}{k-1}$$

Now $$\lim_{k\to l}\frac{e^{\sin(2k)}-e^{\sin(2l)}}{k-1}=e^{\sin(2l)}\cdot\lim_{k\to l}\dfrac{e^{(\sin2k-\sin2l)}-1}{\sin2k-\sin2l}\cdot\lim_{k\to l}\dfrac{\sin2k-\sin2l}{k-l}$$

Use [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html), $\sin2k-\sin2l=2\sin(k-l)\cos(k+l)$