# Solve limit $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2-1}{\ln(x)}$ without using L'Hôpital's rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to solve this limit?

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2-1}{\ln(x)}=\frac00$$

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Please see [the MathJax guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to see how to format your math.

Comment: Not about the question, but that was a troll edit.

Comment: Also, please do not mess up the pretty $\LaTeX$...

Answer (score 2):

Set $x-1=h\iff x=1+h$

$$\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{x^2-1}{\ln x}=\dfrac{\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(h+1)^2-1}h}{\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+h)}h}=?$$

Comment: :D That was pretty neat to see.

Comment: Very neat, but doesn't he still need L'Hôpital for the denominator?

Comment: @O.VonSeckendorff You need **something** to get past the $\ln$, whether it be known limits or series expansion.

Comment: @O.VonSeckendorff, This is an elementary formula of limit, readily available from $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-1}x=1$$ See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690898/determine-the-following-limit-as-x-approaches-0-frac-ln1xx

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I didn't know/remember that one. Good to know.

Comment: @SimpleArt Well the series doesn't use L'Hôpital, as in your answer. I don't know how strict is OP with the requirement of no use of rule.

Comment: @SimpleArt Dr. MV just wrote a really slick proof using an inequality.

Comment: Happy New Year Lab!  If the user is asking about this limit, then surely relying on knowledge of $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\log(1+h)}{h}=1$ is completely circular in my humble opinion.

Comment: @Dr.MV How to define $\ln(x)$ then?

Comment: @SimpleArt See my posted solution and follow the embedded link.

Answer (score 2):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm function satisfies the inequalities

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1} \tag 1$$

for $x>0$.

Hence, we have from $(1)$

$$\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}\le \frac{x^2-1}{\log(x)}\le \frac{x(x^2-1)}{x-1} \tag 2$$

whence application of the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

> $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2-1}{\log(x)}=2$$

Comment: Plz. Check (1).

Comment: @MyGlasses Thank you;  I've edited.  -Mark

Comment: Haha, nice...  :-D

Comment: @SimpleArt Thank you.  And if you follow the link, it will show a way forward that begins with the limit definition of the exponential function.

Answer (score 1):

With substitution $x=e^t$ we have:
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2-1}{\ln x}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{e^{2t}-1}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1+2t+\frac{(2t)^2}{2}-1}{t}=2$$
where
$$e^\theta=1+\theta+\frac{\theta^2}{2}$$

Comment: We can employ $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^x-1}x=1$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee from where? without proof?

Comment: Which identities can be used for limit ? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42679/proof-of-fx-ex-1-x-1-text-as-x-to-0-using-epsilon-delta-definiti  OR http://2000clicks.com/MathHelp/CalculusLimitExponential.aspx

Comment: I mean, it is limit definition to derivative of $e^x$ at $x=0$.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee For using this limit, according to your links, _all_ apply l'hopital rule, derivative definition and Taylor expansion. My suppose is the  part of Taylor expansion also, but I don't know where can find a proof without these techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$\ln(x)=(x-1)-\frac12(x-1)^2+\mathcal O(x^3)$$

and

$$x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$$

So the reciprocal of the limit is

$$\frac1L=\lim_{x\to1}\frac1{x+1}-\frac{(x-1)}{2(x+1)}+\mathcal O\left(\frac{(x-1)^2}{x+1}\right)=\frac12$$

So that

$$L=2$$

Answer (score 0):

By a shift of the variable your limit is equivalent to

$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t(t+1)}{\ln(1+t)}=\frac{\lim_{t\to0}t+1}{\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+t)}t}=2.$$