# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$ without using $\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Here is my attempt at finding a proof that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}  = 1$. We need to show that $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \, \exists \delta > 0$ such that $ 0 < |x| < \delta \implies |\frac{e^x-1}{x} - 1| < \varepsilon$. We can let $\delta = \min(1,?)$ where $?$ is a function of $\varepsilon$. So
$$ \left|\frac{e^x-1}{x} - 1\right| < \varepsilon$$
$$ \left|\frac{e^x-1-x}{x}\right| < \varepsilon$$
The numerator of the function can be bounded by $|x| < \delta \leq 1$:
$$ |e^x-1-x| \leq |e^x| + |x| + 1$$
$$ |e^x| + |x| + 1 \leq e + 1 + 1 \leq e + 2$$
But then the $|x|$ is in the denominator so:
$$ \frac{|e^x-1-x|}{|x|} \nleq e + 2$$
I am not sure what to do now or if there is a better way to approach this problem.
I am new to $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs so any help would be greatly appreciated.
I am specifically looking for an approach that does not appeal to the derivative definition, $\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$, or the power series $e^x  = 1 + x + x^2/2! + \cdots$, wanting to stick only with limits. I am not sure if this is possible, as I assume the definition of $e^x$ must be important to the proof. I had the idea to use something like the squeeze theorem using $\epsilon$-$\delta$, but am not sure which functions to choose.

A definition of $e$ that might work (since it is a limit and does not involve derivatives) is $$ e = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n}$$
But I am not sure how this definition could be used in the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof.

Comment: Which definition of $e^x$ were you given?

Comment: @AnneBauval's comment is important.  You cannot prove this without knowing what $e^x$ means!  For example, if $e^x$ is the inverse of $\ln$, then we have $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1 \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{y \to 1}\frac{y-1}{\ln y}=1$$ so then we can solve this if we know some properties of $\ln$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42679/proof-of-fx-ex-1-x-1-text-as-x-to-0-using-epsilon-delta-definiti?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: another often used definition is that $ e^{x}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}=1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{6}+\dots $
Plugging that into the equation gives u $$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{x}-1}{x}=\frac{1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\dots-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^{2}}{6!}+\dots\right)=1+O\left(x\right) $$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of $ f(x) = (e^x-1)/x = 1 \text{ as } x\to 0$ using epsilon-delta definition of a limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42679/proof-of-fx-ex-1-x-1-text-as-x-to-0-using-epsilon-delta-definiti)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ as the definition of $e$, would taking $e^x := \lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ be acceptable? If it is, then you can deduce the limit using only the binomial theorem and the sum of a geometric series:

For $n \geq 2$, let $\epsilon_n(x) = (1+\frac{x}{n})^n-1-x$. Then
$$
\begin{split}
\epsilon_n(x) &= (1+\frac{x}{n})^n-1-x = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{x^k}{n^k}-1-x\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{n^k}.\frac{x^k}{k!}\\
\end{split}
$$
Now since $1/(1+1)!= 1/2^1$, it follows by induction that $1/(l+1)!\leq 1/2^l$, hence find that for $n\geq 2$ and $|x|<2$
$$
\begin{split}
|\epsilon_n(x)| &\leq \sum_{k=2}^n\frac{n}{n}\frac{(n-1)}{n}\ldots
\frac{(n-k+1)}{n}\frac{|x|^k}{k!}\\ 
&\leq \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{|x|^k}{k!} =|x|\sum_{l=1}^{n-1}\frac{|x|^{l}}{(l+1)!} \leq |x|\sum_{l=1}^{n-1} (\frac{|x|}{2})^l\\
&\leq |x|\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}(\frac{|x|}{2})^l = |x|(\frac{|x|/2}{1-|x|/2})=\frac{|x|^2}{2-|x|}
\end{split} 
$$
But by definition, $\epsilon_n(x) \to e^x-1-x$ as $n \to \infty$,  hence it follows that $|e^x-1-x|\leq \frac{|x|^2}{2-|x|}$, and hence
$$
|\frac{e^x-1}{x}-1|\leq \frac{|x|}{2-|x|} \to 0 \text{ as } x\to 0,
$$
hence $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1$ as required.

Comment: Isn't $k!\ge 2^k$ valid only for $k \ge 4$? Moreover, can you explain why is $\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{|x|^k}{k!} \le |x| \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{|x|^k}{2^k}$? I get it that you have estimated the finite sum with the series and you used the inequality $k! \ge 2^k$, but I don't get why there is a factor $|x|$ that multiplies the series.

Comment: I've edited the answer to try and clarify the estimate -- you're right that $k!\geq 2^k$ for $k\geq 4$, but you can use $(k+1)! \geq 2^k$ instead, which is true for all $k\geq 1$ (same inductive proof, but you get the base case $(1+1)^1=2^1$). The factor of $|x|$ is what gives you the $(l+1)!$ -- the sum starts from $k=2$, so taking $l+1=k$, the sum becomes one that starts at $l=1$, with a $|x|^{l+1}$ out of which you can then take a factor of $|x|$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :D